# Create a fat32 partition on usb

Tags: boot

**EDIT:  Magic, friend formatted it to FAT32. Works now.**

I am trying to create a bootable USB stick to install windows7..

Here is my problem:

And I have real trouble finding a tutorial to do what the prompt wants.

[image]

Comment: if you wish to create a bootable windows 7 ISO, do it by using dd. `dd if=link_to_iso.iso of=usb_device_file` I had written a blog post explaining this, try [this blog post](http://anam.co/blog/node/5)

Comment: Ill check it out :)

Comment: Oh well.. Now I am stuck with : DEFAULT  on the boot.. I give up . Need to get a CD

Answer (score 0):

You can not create a bootable Windows 7 USB with Unetbootin as the snapshot you shared, more over the option to select ISO is not selected in your snapshots

Comment: Thats because I did this only for the snapshot.
So what are my options?

Comment: ok what steps did you take to create bootable Windows 7 on USB , ie which software and what steps you took that can give some clue as where you were stuck

Comment: I am stuck at:  Got the Windows ISO, and a 8GB USB stick.  And UNetbootin on my Ubuntu

Comment: no Unetbootin I have tried myself earlier and it did not worked  I googled https://www.google.co.in/search?q=install+windows+8+from+usb and came with a few links you will have to try some other solution I did not had success with Unetbootin in case you want to format your partition to fat32 use a command `sudo cfdisk` this will show your USB mounted some where in fileysystem from there you can format

Comment: FATAL ERROR: Bad logical partition 6: enlarged logical partitions overlap
                          Press any key to exit cfdisk.
on sudo cfdisk

Comment: see do not use `cfdisk` as `sudo cfdisk /dev/sda3` instead do a just `sudo cfdisk` inside there you will see drives

Comment: FATAL ERROR: Cannot open disk drive
                          Press any key to exit cfdisk